# std::map inserts a NULL pointer

Tags: c++

I ran into an access violation reading error and when I debugged it, I saw that the insert function of std::map is inserting a NULL pointer into the map.

Though I've fixed the error by first inserting a NULL value into the map and then changing that value to the corresponding object I wanted to insert in the map. But I want to know the reason the error occurs and why it got fixed.
My code looks like this:

```
void CTextureBank::AddTexture(int ID)
{
    // Create a CTexture object, load texture into it and insert it into the Texture List
    CTexture* texture = new CTexture();
    texture->LoadTextureFromFile(mRenderer, ID);
    mTextureList.insert(std::make_pair<int, CTexture*>(ID, texture));
}
```

In the AddTexture function, I'm first creating a texture object, loading a texture into it and putting that texture into the map.
But, this one gives me an access violation reading error.

And doing this doesn't:

```
void CTextureBank::AddTexture(int ID)
{
    // Create a CTexture object, load texture into it and insert it into the Texture List
    CTexture* texture = new CTexture();
    texture->LoadTextureFromFile(mRenderer, ID);
    mTextureList.insert(std::make_pair<int, CTexture*>(ID, NULL));
    mTextureList[ID] = texture;
}
```

So it would be great if someone can tell me why this occurs.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard [std::map.insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) **will NOT overwrite existing elements**.

> Because element keys in a map are unique, the insertion operation
>   checks whether each inserted element has a key equivalent to the one
>   of an element already in the container, and if so, the element is not
>   inserted, returning an iterator to this existing element (if the
>   function returns a value).

So if you already have a `mTextureList[ID]` that is `NULL` in your map `mTextureList.insert(std::make_pair<int, CTexture*>(ID, texture));` will do absolutely nothing and leave the `NULL` in place.

Try adding an assert:

```
void CTextureBank::AddTexture(int ID)
{
    // Create a CTexture object, load texture into it and insert it into the Texture List
    assert(mTextureList.find(ID) == mTextureList.end()); // Check if ID already in map

    CTexture* texture = new CTexture();
    texture->LoadTextureFromFile(mRenderer, ID);
    mTextureList.insert(std::make_pair<int, CTexture*>(ID, texture));
}
```

This will tell you if there's already a NULL in the map.

The easy way to always insert and overwrite is to just use `mTextureList[ID] = texture;` and not use `std::map.insert` but you will possibly leak memory if you don't fist delete the previous `CTexture`.

For basic types there is no significant impact to using the `[]` operator to insert/overwrite into a map. The value in the map's pair gets initialized to zero/NULL then overwritten in the assignment.

In fact the cost of passing `std::make_pair` to `.insert` may be larger but this depends on compilers and compiler settings.

```
void CTextureBank::AddTexture(int ID)
{
    // Create a CTexture object, load texture into it and insert it into the Texture List
    CTexture* texture = new CTexture();
    texture->LoadTextureFromFile(mRenderer, ID);

    auto i = mTextureList.find(ID);
    // If you don't have C++11 enabled instead of auto use:
    // std::map<int, CTexture*>::iterator i = mTextureList.find(ID);

    if(i == mTextureList.end()){
        // entry does not exist, insert new one
        mTextureList.insert(std::make_pair<int, CTexture*>(ID, texture));
    } else {
      // There's already an entry of this ID
      if(i->second){
          MESSAGE("WOOPS!, THERE'S ALREADY A TEXTURE WITH THIS ID. IS THIS OKAY?\n");
          delete i->second; // delete old texture ??? Is this safe to do?
      } else {
          MESSAGE("It's just a null, we're fine.\n");
          // Someone probably used mTextureList[ID] which created a NULL
      }
      i->second = texture; // overwrite existing entry's value
    }
}
```

Or shorter:

```
void CTextureBank::AddTexture(int ID)
{
    // Create a CTexture object, load texture into it and insert it into the Texture List
    CTexture* texture = new CTexture();
    texture->LoadTextureFromFile(mRenderer, ID);
    auto result = mTextureList.insert(std::make_pair<int, CTexture*>(ID, texture));
    if(!result.second){
       if(result.first->second != NULL){
           MESSAGE("WOOPS!, THERE'S ALREADY A TEXTURE WITH THIS ID. IS THIS OKAY?\n");
           delete result.first->second; // delete old texture
       }
       result.first->second = texture; // save new texture
    }
}
```

Comment: ***So if you already have a mTextureList[ID]that is NULL in your map mTextureList.insert(std::make_pair<int, CTexture*>(ID, texture)); will do absolutely nothing and leave the NULL in place.*** But it does, it overwrites the NULL and puts a texture into it. So how can this be true?

Comment: @Ashar7 Read the page I linked with the quote http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/ , there's an example at the bottom. **insert does NOT overwrite the existing values**. The documentation is quite clear about that.

Comment: Okay, I got it.